# Angular 4 error message should link to invalid formControl

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms, angular2-formbuilder, angular2-form-validation

I am using the following.

> 1) FormBuilder
>
> 2) FormControl

I have created an error summary to show all the errors on form submit if the formControls input, radio, etc is not valid. What I would like to do is when the user clicks on the error message they should be taken to the input field that is invalid.

A few ways I know I can do it is:

1. `<a href="formControlElementID">Error message</a>`
2. Create a function to set focus on click

I know these can work but I am looking for an Angular specific solution if one exists. I am hoping for some sort of way to link using the form control name.

Ex:

```
<input
  formControlName="signupFirstName"
  matInput/>

<div id="error-summary>
  <a href="signupFirstName><p></p></a>

  or 

  <a angularDirective=""><p></p></a>
</div>
```

Is there anything built in with `FormControl` or Angular to link to a `formControll` input element? It seems redundant to use `<a href="id">` as it would most likely be the same name as the `formControl` as well as it adds `#id` to the url which then adds more work for routing. The javascript way to set focus works but more code.

Based on these I am assuming there must be some sort of built in way to do this by now.

### **Update**

Regarding @Vegas answer. This works well however, if you are using a formgroup you must call the template variable name different or else when passing the value to a child component as well as formControlName it will try and pass the template variable for both.

Incorrect:

```
<input #name formControlName="name">

<child-component [inputName]="name" [inputValidation]="name"
```

As well as trying to use [inputName]=name will cause same issue.

Correct:

```
<input #nameInputField formControlName="name">

<child-component [inputName]="nameInputField" [inputValidation]="name"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways doing it, could be with template variables and ngIf:

```
<form novalidate (submit)="onLoginSubmit()" [formGroup]="user">
    Username <input id="username" type="text" #username autofocus formControlName="username">
    <br><br>
    Name <input id="name" type="text" #name autofocus formControlName="name">
    <ul>
        <li (click)="name.focus()" *ngIf="user.get('username').hasError('required')">Error on username</li>
        <li (click)="username.focus()" *ngIf="user.get('name').hasError('required')">Error on name</li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6lbq4r)

Comment: Is name.focus using the Id / #name or formControlName? As well as will this work in different component? My error message is a component. The form component generates one for each error. Thank you also for taking the time to review.

Comment: "name" is for #name. As for different component, let me think :)

Comment: I will try it out and let you know if it works for child component to reference parent components. This seems like a fairly decent solution. Is there an even better way?

Comment: Worked excellently inside child component. Very useful value to pass in without doing a lot of javascript manipulation. Template variables are awesome. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Much appreciated :)